# Could you invest in a more robust podcast distribution mechanism?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, podcast

So I see a blog post about this week's podcast and I try to download it.  Of course, the download fails as it always does.  It seems I always have to wait until the following day before I can successfully download the recording.  Now I see you have taken down the blog post.  Were you overwhelmed?

What's up with that?  At this point, you are Internet Titans.  You should be streaming live *video* of the podcast and making those videos available for download immediately.  Alright, maybe video is asking a bit much, but there should be no reason I, and as many other people who care to listen, can't at least get the audio immediately.

Comment: Yep, failed for me also, never got to listen to it.

Comment: The blog post [is still up](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/se-podcast-15/), it was just bumped to the second post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's really two separate questions hear and I'll address the two of them distinctly

**1) Why doesn't the download link work:** The blog posts for each podcast are scheduled to go out at 3pm ET every Wednesday (we try to release on a consistent schedule to make it easier for people.  That means the blog post is written, links inserted, and the post scheduled Tuesday night/Wednesday morning and then left to go live per Wordpress's system.  That all worked fine, but unfortunately one of our distribution partners didn't put their end live in time so when you tried to click through on the blog post, you couldn't find the file.  We repointed it to another distribution partner ASAP and its been available through them since early in the evening yesterday.

These issues have now been resolved and you shouldn't see anymore file issues from here out.

**2) Why isn't it available right after taping:** We're not on the business of making a live video podcast, rather we make a pre-recorded audio podcast.  It just so happens, that we think some people might find it interesting to watch, so we setup a camera each week and let anyone who wants watch us do the taping - you'll notice that we don't optimize for video at all (no graphics, only one camera, no skype feeds, no computer feeds, etc).

Because our goal is a high quality audio podcast, there's things that have to be done AFTER taping.  The individual tracks need to be edited, any issues removed, releveled, combined, uploaded to our partners, show notes need to be written and linked, etc.  While we can do this very quickly sometimes (within a few hours of the show finishing), we can't always, and rather than make people guess about when it will be posted, we make it easy by releasing on a consistent schedule.

Comment: I appreciate that you need some time to prep the recording before distributing it.  By "immediately", I meant after it's announced on the blog.  That hasn't been my experience.  I'll see what happens with you new distribution partner.  I take it you're no longer working with ITConversations?  You finally had a reasonable file naming convention (e.g., ITC.SE-StackExchange-2011.08.03.mp3) and now you're back to the gibberish (this week's file was named 1IcQeF88cusY.128.mp3).

Comment: We work with several partners, our first choice for point of distribution is IT Conversations (and we'll be using them in the future) we just need to figure out how to make sure the file is always live at the right time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about the distribution problems, but as for "You should be streaming live video of the podcast", they do just that -- the video is on [Livestream](http://www.livestream.com/stackexchange), and there's a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/512/se-podcast-live-chat) that discusses the podcast every week while it's happening. The reason the audio isn't available immediately is there's almost always miscellaneous problems during recording -- they have trouble connecting with the guest, or there are audio issues; it takes the [producer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159928/alex-miller) some time to clean up the recording before it's posted

Comment: Like ROBOT VOICE. That was an amusing session.

Comment: @Grace I said "issues", not "spectacular gifts"